# How can i display one link instead of multiple links?

Tags: php

```
<?php
include 'preCode.php';
include 'header.php';
echo '<body><div class="standardLayout">';
include 'systemMenu.php';
echo '<h4>All Charges</h4>';

$user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);  
$query = "SELECT * FROM billingItems WHERE  userID= ' ".$user->userID. " '   ORDER BY deliveryTimestamp DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<p>';

    echo '<a href="billingHistory1.php?deliveryTimestamp=' .$row["deliveryTimestamp"]. '">'.
   ' Order Delivered on' . '</a>' .$row['deliveryTimestamp']  ;
}

echo '</div></body></html>';

$_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);
include 'footer.html';
?>
```

output of above file:

```
  All Charges

  Order Delivered on2015-05-06 13:26:50
  Order Delivered on2015-05-06 13:26:50
  Order Delivered on2015-05-06 13:26:50
  Order Delivered on2015-05-03 22:11:23
  Order Delivered on2015-05-03 22:11:23
  Order Delivered on2015-05-03 22:11:23
  Order Delivered on2015-05-03 22:11:23
```

If you will see the output then you will notice that first three links are same and last four are same.

I need to reduce multiple links to one.

Want to display only two links one for each.

To do that, i need to use a if statement inside the while loop. If `deliveredTimestamp` is same don't display it otherwise display it. Please help.

Comment: What if you end up with two orders that come in at the same time? Should this not be pulled by unique ID instead of timestamp?

Comment: You can Achieve this by using `GROUP BY` in your query.

Comment: That's cool. Thank You. My query is working now. Thank You again.

Answer (score 3):

Why not try adding unique deliveryTimestamps to an array and then rendering your links from those?

```
$timestamps = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ( !in_array($row['deliveryTimestamp'], $timestamps)) {
        array_push($timestamps, $row['deliveryTimestamp']);
    }
}
foreach ($timestamps as $timestamp) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<a href="billingHistory1.php?deliveryTimestamp='.$timestamp.'">'.
         ' Order Delivered on' . '</a>' .$timestamp  ;
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by to get the number of records reduced

Use this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM billingItems 
          WHERE  userID= ' ".$user->userID. " ' 
          GROUP BY deliveryTimestamp 
          ORDER BY deliveryTimestamp DESC";
```